# Wordpress search page loading on homepage

Tags: php, wordpress, search

I'm pretty new to Wordpress and I've been building a theme with reverie-master but the only problem is the search page. All the other pages, category, archive, etc are working.

I use this for searching in my header.php :

```
<form method="post" action="<?php echo home_url('/'); ?>" class="search-form" role="search">
    <div class="small-9 columns no-pad">  
        <input type="text" class="search-input" name="s" placeholder="Search" value="" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns no-pad">
       <input class="btn-submit postfix search-input" type="submit" value=""/>
     </div>
```

This shows the search results on the homepage. If I type in "ok" in the search bar it takes me to  example : www.homepage.com when it should be on www.homepage.com/?s=ok. The problem with it being on the home page, the paginations will take you to page 2 of the home blog feed instead on www.homepage.com/page/2/ when it should be something ilke this www.homepage.com/page/2/?s=test

When I manualy type in this url in the browser : www.homepage.com/page/2/?s=test the pagination is working. My problem is the pagination and I am wondering why the posts displays on the homepage(which I assume is the problem)

Here is my search.php code :

```
Starts with <?php get_header(); ?> and ends with <?php get_footer(); ?>
```

This is the loop in between with pagination :

```
<h2><?php _e('Search Results for', 'reverie'); ?> "<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>"</h2>

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>

                <?php /* Start the Loop */ ?>
                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="row pad-row">
                        <div class="large-11 columns bor-bottom">
                            <a class="fade" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><p class="feed-title"><?php the_title(); ?></p></a> 
                            <p class="feed-info">By <span class="feed-author"><?php the_author(); ?> </span> &#149; <?php echo human_time_diff( get_the_time('U'), current_time('timestamp') ) . ' ago'; ?> &#149;  
                            <?php
                            foreach((g_the_category()) as $category) {
                                if ($category->cat_name != 'featured') {
                                    echo '<a href="' . get_category_link( $category->term_id ) . '" title="' . sprintf( __( "View all posts in %s" ), $category->name ) . '" ' . '>' . $category->name.'</a> ';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                            &#149; <span class="feed-cmt"><?php comments_number( '0 Comments', '1 Comments', '% Comments' ); ?>. </span></p>
                            <?php the_excerpt(); ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                <?php endwhile; ?>

                <?php else : ?>
                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'none' ); ?>    
                <?php endif; // end have_posts() check ?>



            <!-- Start Pagination -->

            <div class="row pad-row">
                <div class="large-11 columns pagination-centered large-centered panel-page">
                    <?php /* Display navigation to next/previous pages when applicable */ ?>
                    <?php if ( function_exists('reverie_pagination') ) { reverie_pagination(); } else if ( is_paged() ) { ?>
                        <nav id="post-nav">
                            <div class="post-previous"><?php next_posts_link( __( '&larr; Older posts', 'reverie' ) ); ?></div>
                            <div class="post-next"><?php previous_posts_link( __( 'Newer posts &rarr;', 'reverie' ) ); ?></div>
                        </nav>
                    <?php } ?>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not put search form directly. WP has a functionality to get search form called `get_search_form()`. This function prints wp basic search form, but still you can customize this. In order to customize, you can use a filter called [get_search_form](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_search_form).

```
function custom_search_form( $form ) {
    $form = '<form method="get" action="' . home_url('/') . '" class="search-form" role="search">
    <div class="small-9 columns no-pad">  
        <input type="text" class="search-input" name="s" id="s" placeholder="Search" value="' . get_search_query() . '" />
    </div>
    <div class="small-3 columns no-pad">
       <input class="btn-submit postfix search-input" id="searchsubmit" type="submit" value="'. esc_attr__( 'Search' ) .'"/>
     </div>
    </form>';

    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'custom_search_form' );
```

And put this to **functions.php**